# Ethereum classic wallet is zero

Tags: balances

I logged onto my ethereum classic wallet and the balance is zero. This is absolutely wrong. What do I need to do.

Comment: Then 2 min is showed some of my balance and now it's back to zero

Comment: Error..restart emerald an unexpected errorh has occured.

Comment: Try entering your address in [gastracker](https://gastracker.io/) to verify that your address has Ether on it. If so, something is wrong with your node. You might not be fully synchronized

Answer (score 0):

Check your balance with a Ethereum Classic Blockchain Explorer http://0xeth.com